# How to fix cannot play this video android form url

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

I upload video form recorded by my device

and I get url form my server `http....mp4` to show in videoview

but it's not work

and I try sent video form download other web ,server sent url and this url is work in videoview!

`My problem : How to convert my mp4 form recorded by my device`

and I search internet ,get answer is `FFMPEG` but I have no idea to set it in android studio to convert my video before sent to server

Comment: Add the code what you tried up to now. No need to convert if your video is in mp4 format , because mp4 is supported in Android.

Comment: I select video in device to server and server sent url, i get url to videoview but it's not work

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a Video "), 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also add the relevant permission in manifest.

```
private VideoView videoView;
    private int position = 0;
    private MediaController mediaController;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);


    if (mediaController == null) {
        mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);

        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    }


    try {

        int id = this.getRawResIdByName("yourvideoname");
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + id));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {


            videoView.seekTo(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                videoView.start();
            }


            mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                    // Re-Set the videoView that acts as the anchor for the MediaController
                    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I want to play video from url

Comment: Accept my above answer if it's useful. Change the videoview like this

 Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("YOUR_VIDEO_URL");
        try {
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: i get error `E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)` and have dialog show `cannot play this video`